# Is it worth to migrate from Angular 2 to Angular 4?

Tags: migration, angular

Hello SO community and Angularians!

So, I am midway developing a huge platform in Angular 2. And I realized that many external libraries and dependencies for Angular 2 are migrating to the new Angular 4. Giving me many errors, obviously.

I could fork these libraries and use the forked versions and subscribe to main library development or, I could just upgrade to Angular 4 my project.

Questions to be answered in order to determinate if it's worth for me to migrate:

- **Compatibility with Angular 2.4**

I have found some adaptations to ensure compatibility with legacy, like this: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/e99d721

- **Changes app wide**

Do I have to go through my whole app and start fixing things?

I mean, are main functionalities reworked in such way that I will have to review many of them?

Or, are there many build/core incompatibilities that will keep me days occupied fixing compile errors/warnings instead of developing?

**I am not asking for someone to do the research for me**, I am asking people that maybe already went through this process or simply know well both versions in order to give me some experience tips, clarifications, etc.

At the moment, I am doing my research here:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
- http://angularjs.blogspot.it/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html
- https://learninglaravel.net/angular-4-new-features-and-improvements

**UPDATE**

**I just migrated to Angular 4**. The link that @PierreDuc put in his answer is a very nice tool to have a decent guideline in the migration process.

I would recommend:

1. Read new features and update yourself with Angular 4. This was specially useful: https://angularjs.blogspot.it/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html
2. Follow Angular's guideline and modify your project: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

I would also recommend to commit your current project, create a new branch in your dev repository and proceed with migration in that branch.

**An issue that I encountered**:
`Input`, `Output` and `ContentChild` will be imported from a wrong path.

*My case:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestro } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, ContentChild } from "@angular/core/src/metadata/directives";
```

*Solution:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you check the changelog there are a couple things you need to keep in mind:

**Before updating**

- Ensure you don't use extends `OnInit`, or use extends with any lifecycle event. Instead use `implements <lifecycle event>`.
- Stop using `DefaultIterableDiffer`, `KeyValueDiffers#factories`, or `IterableDiffers#factories`
- Stop using deep imports, these symbols are now marked with `ɵ` and are
  not part of our public API.
- Stop using `Renderer.invokeElementMethod` as this method has been
  removed. There is not currently a replacement.

**During the update**

- Update all of your dependencies to version 4 and the latest typescript.
- If you are using Linux/Mac, you can use: `npm install
  @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@4.0.0
  typescript@latest --save`
- If you use animations in your application, you should import
  `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` in
  your App `NgModule`.
- Replace `RootRenderer` with `RendererFactory2`.
- Replace `Renderer` with `Renderer2`.

**After the update**

- Rename your `template` tags to `ng-template`.
- Replace `OpaqueTokens` with `InjectionTokens`.
- If you call `DifferFactory.create(...)` remove the `ChangeDetectorRef`
  argument.
- Replace `ngOutletContext` with `ngTemplateOutletContext`.
- Replace `CollectionChangeRecord` with `IterableChangeRecord`

[source](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed I was looking for this kind of information even though I didn't explain myself in the best of ways. I will use this as a sort of guideline in order to make my migration less painful.

Comment: @SrAxi I'm working a very large and complex system as well, and I must say that I had little to no issue switching to `v4`. Most of the times the issues arose from `angular-cli`

Comment: Great! I am using `angular-cli`myself! :D But I have to say that I am still at a good point to switch, it's not too late. I hope my external libraries update aswell to `v4`, anyway, will be something that everyone would have to do sooner or later.

Comment: what should we use for differs? any link?

Answer (score 2):

Angular team has announced , let's not call angular 2 or angular 4 let's call it Angular and there will be major update for every 6 months.I have faced the issue in angular v4.0.0 so change the configuration in webpack

```
  new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
                // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
                /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
                helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
                {} // a map of your routes
            ),
```

And install **@angular/animations** package and import in app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ]
})
```

I will prefer to update to latest version of angular. Angular V4.0.0 has reduced the packages weight and they have increased the performance.

Comment: Thanks! Is good to know that they have reduced the packages weight! :D