# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations'

Tags: angular, angular-material, npm-install

After using "npm install" and starting local server by "npm start" I started getting this error:-

```
ERROR in ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in '/home/ashvini/Desktop/HN-Angular2/node_modules/@angular/material/@angular'
 @ ./~/@angular/material/@angular/material.es5.js 20:0-81
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts`enter code here`
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

This is related to angular material design but I am not able to understand what I need to do to resolve this issue.

Before "npm install" it was working fine.

Comment: I assume you need to import the `AnimationModule` in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Hey @alexkucksdorf, did you mean BrowserAnimationsModule,

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In `app.module` add this:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

And lather in the module add it to `imports`:

```
imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule]
```

And remove the `@angular/animations` import statement.

Maybe by applying `npm install` you updated your Angular version from v.2 to v.4.

**UPDATE:**

or just add this to your `package.json` *(Choose the version you need)*:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
}
```

Once you added this to your dependencies, apply `npm install` again.

**UPDATE 2:**

Even a quicker way:

```
npm install @angular/animations --save
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error

`ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve @angular/platform-browser/animations relative to /home/ashvini/Desktop/HN-Angular2/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in /home/ashvini/Desktop/HN-Angular2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/ashvini/Desktop/HN-Angular2/src/app/app.module.ts

ERROR in /home/ashvini/Desktop/HN-Angular2/src/app/app.module.ts (2,41): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/animations'.)`

Comment: Try to do what I explain on my Update. Initially I thought you updated your Angular version, but I think you just lack the dependency for `@angular/animations`.

Comment: Apply `npm install`after you added the dependencies. But undo the first thing that I said, the `BrowserAnimationsModule` modification.

Comment: @Ashvini Check my second update. That should solve the error that you posted.

Comment: Hey @SrAxi, thanks for your response. With the first update that error is resolved but now I have another saying 

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ng-template' is not a known element:`

Comment: @Ashvini I'm glad my answer solved your problem. Your new error is because in Angular 4 `<template>` becomes `<ng-template>`. So, if you are using a library that upgraded to Angular 4 and has code with `<ng-template>`, your Angular 2 won't understand it and throws an error. You could solve this by: 1. Migrating your project to Angular 4. 2. Changing your libraries for others compatible with Angular 2. 3. Fork your libraries project in Github and adapt the code to your Angular version. I recommend the first option.

Comment: @Ashvini If you have more questions about this I suggest you do some research on Angular 4. This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116428/is-it-worth-to-migrate-from-angular-2-to-angular-4
Anyways, your OP (Original Post) has been answered if I am not mistaken. Good luck mate! ;)

Comment: Even faster way `npm i @angular/animations --save` ;)

Comment: I also had to add `'@angular/animations':'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js'` to my `systemjs.config.js`.

Answer (score 6):

In package.json remove (^) "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2". In latest angualr.material we are getting this error.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

npm install will install the latest Angular Framework, which is now 4.

the solution is above mentioned already by others.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid this is commentary on another post, not an answer.

Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score -4):

I search a lot seriously then I found that in my project

```
node_modules/@angular/
```

I have by mistake have to install file which due to error install half and named animation So as I delete that file error get solved.I think it may be due to multiple files on root and project folder.

Comment: I have an error due to a confusion of animation file.