# node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'AnimationDriver'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created a project that uses Anuglar 2 + asp .net core template in Visual Studio 2017. I upgraded my project from Angular 2.0 to 4.0 I have followed the steps mentioned here [Upgrading from Angular 2.0 to 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116428/is-it-worth-to-migrate-from-angular-2-to-angular-4/43116982#43116982)

But I am still getting the following error:

> node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'AnimationDriver'

Please advise.

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15332

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save

Then run whatever ng serve or npm start command you normally use, and everything should work.

If you rely on Animations, import the new BrowserAnimationsModule from @angular/platform-browser/animations in your root NgModule. Without this, your code will compile and run, but animations will trigger an error. Imports from @angular/core were deprecated, use imports from the new package import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';.

here: http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

Comment: Issue is with Visual Studio 2017 and the SPA pack, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15332

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. I had tried both the above mentioned solutions but it was not working for me. The problem was, I had upgraded the new packages without deleting the existing files in node_modules folder. Hence after upgrading, the platform-browser files were not updating correctly (the animations folder was not getting added to platform-browser folder after upgrade). So I deleted all the existing files in node_modules folder, and ran the upgrade. This time it installed all packages from scratch, instead of updating existing packages. That resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's angular2-universal module that's causing this error, if you disable it you won't have it anymore.. No idea if there are workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

In the normal, it is because of the incompatible version of angular. You should use same angular version for all modules.